# percorerr um array em loop

Tags: javascript, array, loop, for

Olá, preciso entender uma atividade que estou fazendo sobre JS básico:

tenho um array contendo os 8 dias da semana, a atividade consiste em passar o dia (que estamos) e a quantidade de dias para avançar (ex.: passar "Segunda" e avançar 8 dias a partir do dia passado).

Porém não sei bem como fazer isso, já que na minha função determinei este array com todos os dias e desejo percorre-lo a partir do dia passado. Tem algum metodo que posso usar dentro do laço for para percorrer ele até o final e recomeçar até que chegue no dia desejado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em português! Para ter melhor proveito da plataforma, coloque o código como texto e não como imagem. Melhore a pergunta, 8 dias da semana confunde.

Comment: Veja https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma função em javascript chamdada [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), onde você consegue encontrar o índice de determinado elemento em uma array.

Uma vez que definiu o array inicial na sua função, você pode utilizar essa função para poder encontrar qual o índicie do dia inicial e então a partir dele realizar um cálculo de módulo para determinar qual o dia para o qual você vai avançar.

Sendo assim

```js
function avancarDias(diaInicial="QUA", diasParaAvancar=9){
  //digamos que o diaInicial é QUA e queremos avançar 9 dias.
  const DIAS_DA_SEMANA = 7;
  const dias = ["SEG", "TER", "QUA", "QUI", "SEX", "SAB", "DOM"]
  
  //agora utilizamos a função findIndex para achar o índice do dia inicial
  //A função recebe como parâmetro uma função de busca, caso não esteja acostumado(a)
  //com a sintaxe, dá uma pesquisada que é simples de entender.
  const indiceInicial = dias.findIndex(dia => dia == diaInicial);
  
  //Sabendo que queremos avançar 9 dias, vamos somar o índice inicial aos dias para avançar
  
  const total = indiceInicial + diasParaAvancar;
  
  //e então realizar a operação de módulo simbolizada por '%'
  
  const diaResultante = total%DIAS_DA_SEMANA;
  
  //Ao final, subtraímos -1 pois estamos contando o dia de partida como um dia passado;
  return dias[diaResultante - 1];
}

console.log(avancarDias())
//O resultado deveria ser quinta-feira;
```

Uma coisa importante, é entender o funcionamento da função de módulo. Ela simplesmente nos dá o resto de uma divisão.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira que pensei para poder resolver esse problema não usa nenhum laço. Ela calcula a quantidade de dias (8) mais a posição do dia informado ('Segunda-feira') no vetor (no caso a posição 0) e encontra a posição correspondente usando o [operador módulo (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder). Dá uma olhada:

```js
const dias = ['Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'];

function avancarDias(dia, quantidade) {
    let posicaoInit = parseInt(dias.indexOf(dia));

    if (posicaoInit !== -1) {
        let novaPosicao = posicaoInit + quantidade;

        if (novaPosicao >= dias.length) {
            // Caso a nova posição não exista no vetor de dias, usamos o módulo (%) para obter a posição correspondente:
            return dias[novaPosicao % dias.length];
        }

        return dias[novaPosicao];
    }

    return 'O dia informado é inválido!';
}

var dia = 'Segunda-feira';
var quantidade = 8;
console.log(avancarDias(dia, quantidade)); // 'Terça-feira'
```

Qualquer dúvida, manda aí que a gente descobre juntos .